# Spring XD - Could not find module with name 'ftphdfs' and type 'source'

Tags: http, apache-spark, hdfs, spring-integration, spring-xd

I running spring-xd-1.3.1.RELEASE run-time container, when I tried to module file with the source from ftp to hdfs, I get an exception in the shell command which is given below.

```
xd:>module info --name source:ftphdfs
   Command failed org.springframework.xd.rest.client.impl.SpringXDException: Could
   not find module with name 'ftphdfs' and type 'source'
```

Also when I tried to use source as http endpoint, I get an exception like this in shell command which is given below.

```
                    xd:>module info --name source:http  
                            Information about source module 'http':
                            Injects data from http endpoint.

                              Option Name            Description

                                       Default
                            Type
                              ---------------------  -------------------------------------------------------
                            --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            ---------  -------------------------------------------------------------------
                            ---------------------------------
                              https                  true for https://

                                       false
                            boolean
                              maxContentLength       the maximum allowed content length

                                       1048576
                            int
                              messageConverterClass  the name of a custom MessageConverter class, to convert
                             HttpRequest to Message; must have a constructor with a 'MessageBuilderFactory'
                            parameter  org.springframework.integration.x.http.NettyInboundMessageConverter
                            java.lang.String
                              port                   the port to listen to

                                       9000
                            int
                              sslPropertiesLocation  location (resource) of properties containing the locati
                            on of the pkcs12 keyStore and pass phrase
                                       classpath:httpSSL.properties
                            java.lang.String
                              outputType             how this module should emit messages it produces

                                       <none>
                            org.springframework.util.MimeType
```

Tech stack which I'm currently using is given below.
      1) Hadoop 2.7.2 
      2) Spring-XD-1.3.1.RELEASE 
      3) Redis 2.6 (Windows Version) - I use this as a transport 
      4) Zoo-Keeper 3.8

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a `job` not a stream `source`...

```
xd:>module info job:ftphdfs
Information about job module 'ftphdfs':
...
```

I don't see an exception for `source:http` above - just a description of the source.